# Solving Ax = 0 , pivot variables, free varaibles, need more specific explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Recently i started to lear linear algebra out of MIT OpenCourceWare. But i cant quite understand one little 'proof' (demontration) of getting $N(A)$ out of expression $Ax = 0$ by creating rref form of matrix. Given point is at minute 28:05 in [this video](https://youtu.be/VqP2tREMvt0?t=1685)

So basically what i cant understand is that..

We have $Ax = 0$ in form of :

$$
\begin{bmatrix} I & F \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -F \\ I \end{bmatrix}=0
$$

Also the matrices sizes are :

$
r = rank(A) \\
A^{n\times m} \\
I^{r\times r} \\
F^{r\times (n-r)}
$

So i really cant grasp this idea when there is $ (n-r) \neq r$ because then we cant express second matrix $x$ (because those blocks of I and F are not of the same width...)

So I want to ask, where to find better explanation of this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two $I$'s don't need to be the same size, the one in the $2 \times 2$ block matrix is $r \times r$ and the one in the block column matrix is $(n - r) \times (n - r)$.

Comment: Ahh yea, thank you so much I trought those are the same I matrixes .

Comment: But.. then.... then the A matrix is of width $r + (n - r) = n $ and the second matrix has height of $ 2*(n-r) $ and this is possible only when $2r = n$  because $n = 2*(n-r)$ because we want to multiply those two matrices.. am I Right?

Comment: The matrix $F$ has $r$ rows so the second matrix has $r + (n - r) = n$ rows.

Comment: Yeah.. true.. Thank you. I think i need a pause